# Arduino + WizFi 210 (WiFi) HTTP POST

Tags: arduino-mega, wifi

I would like to do an HTTP POST to Carriots. I saw a few tutorials.

Both of them are using ethernet instead of WiFi. I realize the ways of using Arduino WiFi shield and WizFi Shield are a bit different. What do I need to do to run a basic server using the WizFi Shield?

Code:

```c
/******************************************************************
 WizFiShield Web Client Test Example
*****************************************************************/

// WizFiShield communicates using SPI, so include the SPI library:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WizFi2x0.h>
#include <WizFiClient.h>
#include <TimerOne.h>

#define SSID    "EricLeong3"        // SSID of your AP
#define Key     "ericChoong91"  // Key or Passphrase
// Wi-Fi security option (NO_SECURITY, WEP_SECURITY, WPA_SECURITY, WPA2PSK_SECURITY)
#define Security        WPA2PSK_SECURITY
#define APIKEY  "xxxxxxxxx" // Replace with your Carriots apikey
#define DEVICE  "fypSensors@eric3231559.eric3231559"

WizFi2x0Class myWizFi;
WizFiClient myClient;
TimeoutClass ConnectInterval;
boolean Wifi_setup = false;

///////////////////////////////
// 1msec Timer
void Timer1_ISR() {
  myWizFi.ReplyCheckTimer.CheckIsTimeout();
}
//
//////////////////////////////

void setup() {
  byte retval;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("\r\nSerial Init");
  // initalize WizFi2x0 module:
  myWizFi.begin();
  ConnectInterval.init();
  // Socket Creation with Server IP address and Server Port num 
  myClient =  WizFiClient("82,223,244,60", 80);
  // Timer1 Initialize
  Timer1.initialize(1000); // 1msec
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(Timer1_ISR);
  myWizFi.SendSync();
  myWizFi.ReplyCheckTimer.TimerStart(3000);
  Serial.println("Send Sync data");
  while(1) {
    if(myWizFi.CheckSyncReply()) {
      myWizFi.ReplyCheckTimer.TimerStop();
      Serial.println("Rcvd Sync data");
      break;
    }
    if(myWizFi.ReplyCheckTimer.GetIsTimeout()) {
      Serial.println("Rcving Sync Timeout!!");
      // Nothing to do forever;
      for(;;)
      ;
    }
  }
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // AP association  
  while(1) {
    retval = myWizFi.associate(SSID, Key, Security, true);
    if(retval == 1) {
      Serial.println("AP association Success");
      Wifi_setup = true;
      break;
    } else {
      Serial.println("AP association Failed");
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("apleleee ");
  uint8_t retval;
  retval = myClient.connect();
  if(retval == 1) {
    String json = "{\"protocol\":\"v2\",\"device\":\""+String(DEVICE)+"\",\"at\":\"now\",\"data\":{\"Air Temperature\":\"58\",\"Humidity\":\"59\"}}";
    Serial.println("Connected! ");
    //myClient.write((byte *)"GET /search?q=WizFi210 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
    myClient.write((byte *)"POST /streams HTTP/1.1");
    myClient.write((byte *)"Host: api.carriots.com");
    myClient.write((byte *)"Accept: application/json");
    myClient.write((byte *)"User-Agent: Arduino-Carriots");
    myClient.write((byte *)"Content-Type: application/json");
    myClient.write((byte *)"carriots.apikey: ");
    myClient.write((byte *)APIKEY);
    myClient.write((byte *)"Content-Length: ");
    byte thisLength = json.length();
    myClient.write(thisLength);
    myClient.write((byte *)"Connection: close");
    myClient.write((byte *)"");
    myClient.write((byte *)"{\"protocol\":\"v2\",\"device\":\"");
    myClient.write((byte *)DEVICE);
    myClient.write((byte *)"\",\"at\":\"now\",\"data\":{\"Air Temperature\":");
    myClient.write((byte *)"58");
    myClient.write((byte *)",\"Humidity\":");
    myClient.write((byte *)"59");
    myClient.write((byte *)"}}");
  } else
    Serial.println("Connection Failed");
  }
```

The response I get on the serial monitor

```
Serial Init
Send Sync data
Rcvd Sync data
AT

Rcvd Reply: [ERROR]
[ERROR]
Timeout  with ERROR reply
AP association Failed
AT

Rcvd Reply: õAT
õAT
-1

Rcvd Reply: [ERROR: INVALID INPUT]
[ERROR
INVALID
INPUT]
-1

Rcvd Reply: AT
AT
-1

Rcvd Reply: [OK]
[OK]
ATE0

Rcvd Reply: ATE0
ATE0
-1

Rcvd Reply: [OK]
[OK]
AT+XDUM=0

Rcvd Reply: [OK]
[OK]
AT+BDATA=1

Rcvd Reply: [OK]
[OK]
AT+WD

Rcvd Reply: [OK]
[OK]
AT+WM=0

Rcvd Reply: [OK]
[OK]
AT+WPAPSK=EricLeong3,ericChoong91

Rcvd Reply: Computing PSK from SSID and PassPhrase...
Computing
PSK
from
SSID
and
PassPhrase...
-1

Rcvd Reply: [OK]
[OK]
AT+NDHCP=1

Rcvd Reply: [OK]
[OK]
AT+WA=EricLeong3

Rcvd Reply:     IP              SubNet         Gateway   
    IP              SubNet         Gateway   
IP
SubNet
Gateway

Rcvd Reply:  192.168.1.42: 255.255.255.0: 192.168.1.1
 192.168.1.42: 255.255.255.0: 192.168.1.1
192.168.1.42
192.168.1.42
255.255.255.0
255.255.255.0
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.1

Rcvd Reply: [OK]
[OK]
AP association Success
apleleee 
AT+DNSLOOKUP=82,223,244,60,3,5

Rcvd Reply: [ERROR: INVALID INPUT]
Token: [ERROR
```

May I know what's wrong with the code? Why does it show a token error instead of success? What I am trying to do is posting an HTTP POST request to Carriots, which is a place to do my m2m things. I am still wondering which part I am missing. I referred to few sources such as

http://forum.carriots.com/index.php/topic/61-wireless-gardening-with-arduino-cc3000-wifi-modules/page-2

https://github.com/Wiznet/WizFiShield

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE. I'm sorry we can't provide general tutorials here. Is there a specific issue you're struggling with?

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield I had edit the question.hopefully i can get some help here

Comment: What he meant was asking for a tutorial somewhere is generally not accepted since we strive to be the information, not a collection of links. I edited your question to narrow it down a bit...

Answer (score 1):

[The library provides an example for a server.](https://github.com/Wiznet/WizFiShield/blob/master/Software/WizFiShield/examples/WizFiWebServerTest/WizFiWebServerTest.ino)

Here's what it looks like:

```
/******************************************************************
 WizFiShield Web Server Test Example

 A simple web server that shows "Hello World" string 

 Circuit:
 WizFi2x0 connected to Arduino via SPI

 RST: pin 2  // Output
 DRDY: pin 3  // Input
 CSB: pin 4  // output
 MOSI: pin 11  // output
 MISO: pin 12  // input
 SCK: pin 13  // out

 Created 27 Sep. 2012
 by James YS Kim  (jameskim@wiznet.co.kr, javakys@gmail.com)

 Modified 27 May. 2013
 by Jinbuhm Kim  (jbkim@wiznet.co.kr, jinbuhm.kim@gmail.com)
*****************************************************************/

// WizFi210 communicates using SPI, so include the SPI library:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WizFi2x0.h>
#include <WizFiClient.h>
#include <WizFiServer.h>
#include <TimerOne.h>

#define SSID    ""        // SSID of your AP
#define Key     ""  // Key or Passphrase
// Wi-Fi security option (NO_SECURITY, WEP_SECURITY, WPA_SECURITY, WPA2PSK_SECURITY)
//#define Security        WPA_SECURITY

#define MAX_SOCK_NUM    4

unsigned int SrcPort = 80;

WizFi2x0Class myWizFi;
WizFiClient myClient[MAX_SOCK_NUM];//(SIP, ServerPort);
WizFiServer myServer(SrcPort);

boolean Wifi_setup = false;

///////////////////////////////
// 1msec Timer
void Timer1_ISR()
{
  myWizFi.ReplyCheckTimer.CheckIsTimeout();
}
//
//////////////////////////////
void setup() {
  byte retval, i;

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("\r\nSerial Init");

  for(i=0; i<MAX_SOCK_NUM; i++)
    myClient[i] =  WizFiClient();

  myWizFi.begin();

  // Timer1 Initialize
  Timer1.initialize(1000); // 1msec
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(Timer1_ISR);

  myWizFi.SendSync();
  myWizFi.ReplyCheckTimer.TimerStart(3000);

  Serial.println("Send Sync data");

  while(1)
  {
    if(myWizFi.CheckSyncReply())
    {
      myWizFi.ReplyCheckTimer.TimerStop();
      Serial.println("Rcvd Sync data");
      break;
    }
    if(myWizFi.ReplyCheckTimer.GetIsTimeout())
    {
      Serial.println("Rcving Sync Timeout!!");
      return;
    }
  }

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // AP association  
  while(1)
  {
    byte tmpstr[32];

    retval = myWizFi.associate(SSID, Key, Security, true);

    if(retval == 1){
      myWizFi.GetSrcIPAddr(tmpstr);
      Serial.println("WizFi2xo AP Associated");
      Serial.print("MY IPAddress: ");
      Serial.println((char *)tmpstr);
      Wifi_setup = true;
      break;
    }else{
      Serial.println("AP association Failed");
    }
  }

  if(myServer.begin())
    Serial.println("Server Listen OK");
  else
    Serial.println("Server Listen Failed");
}

void loop()
{
  uint8_t retval, i;
  byte rcvdBuf[129];

  memset(rcvdBuf, 0, 129);

  if(Wifi_setup)
  {  
    myWizFi.RcvPacket();
    for(i=0; i<MAX_SOCK_NUM; i++)
    {
      if(myClient[i].available()){    
         retval = myClient[i].read(rcvdBuf);   
         if(retval > 0)
         {
           Serial.print("CID[");
           Serial.print((char)myClient[i].GetCID());
           Serial.print("]");
           Serial.println((char *)rcvdBuf);

           if((rcvdBuf[retval - 1] == 0x0A) && (rcvdBuf[retval - 2] == 0x0D) && (rcvdBuf[retval - 3] == 0x0A) && (rcvdBuf[retval - 4] == 0x0D))
           {
             Serial.print("Receiving Completed");
             myClient[i].write((byte *)"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
             myClient[i].write((byte *)"Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
             myClient[i].write((byte *)"\r\n");
             myClient[i].write((byte *)"Hello World !\r\n");

             delay(100);
             myClient[i].disconnect();
           }
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Using the `WizFiServer` class, it seems to assign a `WizFiClient` instance to each HTTP socket connection. It can then call `clientName.write( /* Data to be sent to client */ );` and `clientName.read();` to get values.

Once it is done with the client, it can free up resources by calling `clientName.disconnect();`.